# Zeppelin Notebook %pyspark interpreter vs %python interpreter

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

What's the difference between `%python` and `%pyspark` in a Zeppelin notebook (screenshot below)?

- I can run the same python commands with both cases (like `print('hello')`)

  - <strike>I can use the the same PySpark API in both cases</strike>
  - <strike>i.e. `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`, and `spark.read.csv`</strike>
  - **EDIT 10/31/2019** This is no longer true; in a `%python` interpreter I get the message `No module named pyspark`.
  - I guess I can install the missing module using `pip install pyspark`, but I **don't know how to install onto a Zeppelin resource.**
- **EDIT 10/31/2019** I must use a `python` interpreter, vs a `python3` interpreter, else I get an error like:
  `Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.`

  - Also, I guess this module was installed on Zeppelin when I used it earlier this year.
- <strike>I can even toggle back and forth; using them both *simultaneously*?</strike>

  - <strike>i.e. first paragraph uses `%python`, next paragraph uses `%pyspark`</strike>
  - Nevermind; each language cannot see the variables defined by the other language...
  - They just have the same (Python) API, i.e. each can create their own dataframe `spark.createDataFrame([...])`
- I see from the screenshot below that those languages use different
  *interpeters*:

  - `%python` language  -> `python` interpreter
  - `%pyspark` language -> `spark` interpreter

...But what's the difference between using those interpreters, if my API / code is all the same? Is either of them faster/newer/better? Why use one over the other?

[image: a zeppelin notebook settings dialog, showing 3 interpreters (spark, python, md) and in the spark interpreter a list of languages including %pyspark, and in python interpreter a list of languages including %python]

Comment: `%pyspark` creates a spark context automatically with the defined parameters (loading spark packages, settings...) for the spark-interpreter. In `%python` you can create a spark context by your own but it is not down automatically.

Comment: Yes, you mean `%pyspark` will implicitly define a `spark` variable / session for me, whereas with `%python` I must create the `spark` variable / session myself, manually? I see that difference saves me some work when using `%pyspark`, although I wonder what settings it uses to create the session (i.e. `appName('...')`) Thank you! If you post this as answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a `%pyspark` paragraph, zeppelin will create a spark context (spark variable) automatically with the defined parameters (loading spark packages, settings...).* Have a look at the [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html)) of the spark-interpreter for some of the possibilities.

In `%python` paragraph you can create a spark context by your own but it is not done automatically and will not use the defined parameters of the spark interpreter section.

That maybe still doesn't seem to be much, but zeppelin can handle multiple users (even if it is currently not perfect) and from an administrative perspective this becomes really handy. An administrator for example can define that every zeppelin user who wants to use spark (scala, R or python), gets the same defined environment (number of executors, memory, software packages of a certain version). It is still possible to workaround this restrictions, but at least you avoid unintentional configuration differences.

*For example:

```
%pyspark
spark
```

Would evaluate to this output output:

```
<SparkContext master=local[4] appName=ZeppelinHub>
```

and

```
%pyspark
spark
```

Would evaluate to this output:

```
<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession at 0x7fe757ca1f60>
```

Comment: Two main differences (benefits) of using `%pyspark`: automatic `spark` variable, and configurability (i.e. administration). If `spark` is my default interpreter, what language is it? i.e. I execute `spark` and the output is ` org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` -- looks like a [Java](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html) or Scala object? I'll guess it's a `%spark` default, [according to your link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html); that is "a Scala environment"?

Comment: `%spark` gives you a Scala environment because it is the same language as which spark was written in (see Matei Zaharia [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/31bkue/im_matei_zaharia_creator_of_spark_and_cto_at/) for his reasons). Most of the pyspark functions also just call the Spark Java API via [Py4J](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals).

Comment: Great, so `%spark` interpreter uses `Scala`  by default. Seems like `Java` and `Scala` are friendly; so *Spark Java API* can run the Scala, and then you say the PySpark runs the Java. Glad to learn these differences, thanks!